# Is there a way to do an If IE8 check with meta tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, meta-tags

or maybe javascript?
I have a layout that works well in ie7 + modern browsers. But not ie8.

I found out that I can use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

and IE8 pretends to be IE7, and renders everything correctly, but then it messes up all the good browsers (webkit-based, gecko-based, etc).

I know that in the body, you can do things like:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    ie8 specific javascript, html, or css
<![endif]-->
```

But I tried that in the `<head>` around the meta tag, but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that since I'm using ruby on rails, I can just ask the request variable what browser asked to get the page.

```
<% if request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] =~ /MSIE 8.0/%>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
<% end %>
```